# Accessing related entity of an entity stored in HttpSession

Tags: jpa, struts2

I have an image upload/store application in which I have a User entity having multiple related images(`List<Image> images` using OneToMany relationship). I am iterating images of the user in session using struts `iterator` tag in *Home.jsp*

```
<s:iterator value="#session['user'].images" status="itStatus">
<s:property value="imageid"/>
<s:property value="name"/>
<s:url action="GetImageAction" var="imgUrl">
<s:param name="imageId" value="imageid"></s:param>
</s:url>  
<li>
<img src="<s:property value="#imgUrl"/>"/>
</li>
</s:iterator>
```

The upload form is on the same page so when the user logs in, he can see the images he has already uploaded & can also upload new images.

Here is my problem. When a new image is uploaded, the same page refreshes to show his images but the recently uploaded image does not get displayed(appears as broken) but I am able to see all previously uploaded images. This is because the `imageId` field of `Image` is having the value `0` in this case instead of the correct id. `GetImageAction` action sets the inputstream from the image using the param `imageId`

Here is the `Image` class:

```
@Entity(name="Images")
public class Image implements Serializable {    
    private long imageid;
    private String name;
    private byte[] image;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Image() {
        super();
    }   

    public Image(String name, byte[] image) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Id")
    public long getImageid() {
        return this.imageid;
    }

    public void setImageid(long id) {
        this.imageid = id;
    }
        ...
}
```

Now I am guessing this is because the new `Image` object iterated is having the default long value `0` instead of the generated Id (I am able to access other fields' values like `name`). Why is this? Since the image is already persisted by the time the result is displayed, shouldn't the Id value be retrieved correctly? What am I doing wrong here?

Please help. I feel I may be missing something simple here but it just wouldn't get solved.

Edit:
`UserAddImageAction`

```
public class UserAddImageAction implements SessionAware {
    private User user;
    private Map session;
    private File photo;
    private String photoContentType;
    private String photoFileName;

    public String execute() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StrTest1");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction etx = em.getTransaction();

        try {           
            BufferedInputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(photo));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int c;
            while((c=i.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(c);
            }
            user = (User) session.get("user");

            user.getImages().add(new Image(photoFileName, baos.toByteArray()));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        etx.begin();
        em.merge(user);
        etx.commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
        session.put("user", user);
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
     ...
```

Comment: Show the code where you persisting images.

Comment: Try `user = em.merge(user);` or fetch `user` after commiting.